# Lightning Bundle fails to use external libraries after LockerService is Enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service, libraries

I am developing a component, that shows a set of photos, in a simple div, and then, by clicking one of them opens up gallery popup. I have successfully imported my external Javascript libraries as Static Resources, as the CSP demands to. The look of the Lightning App, is this simple page:

[image]

**In an execution where the Locker Service is disabled, this is what I get, after clicking one image(the expected behaviour):**

[image]

**Problem:** when I want to try the bundle with the LockerService enabled, I get an error message that I find it difficoult to figure out what precisely might have gone wrong. The screenshot of the message:

[image]

**Repro the use case:**

In this [folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4_lj7szoq5yWVFLMTdoMU83R1U) in GDrive, you can find all the necessary files to use in order to reproduce the use case.

Thanks in advance,
E.

Comment: It would be very much helpful if you could list out the names of the external libraries used along with this question. Also, rather than providing Google Drive link to reproduce the same, would be better if you could provide a link to install an unmanaged package.

Comment: @SE_User: That's correct. Will keep that in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what version of lightGallery you're using in your provided source, but it appears to be outdated. If you upgrade to a newer version plus take a couple additional steps this repro should work:

1. Download the latest version of [lightGallery](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/blob/master/dist/js/lightgallery.js)
2. In your helper file change the line `lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'));` to `$("#lightgallery").lightGallery();`
3. Update `<ltng:require>` to import jquery before lightGallery since lightGallery has a dependency on jquery being loaded first.

After these mods the behavior for the app is the same with and without LockerService enabled.

---

If you're curious why your version of lightGallery doesn't work here are the technical details. First, it uses CustomEvent and there's a small issue in LockerService code here. It's a 1 line fix that I anticipate won't take long to be fixed in production. Once past that issue, lightGallery tries to call `insertAdjacentHTML` on `document.body`. This behavior is intentionally blocked by LockerService since document.body is a shared element. Inside Locker, you (and the libs you use) should only be messing with the DOM you directly own.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I made the changes that you suggested, and yes tha gallery works, but unfortunatelly, partiali. What I mean by this is that for example: the counter of the pages (1/2) or (2/2), never gets updated while I'm browsing the photos. I also lost the thumbnail bar of the photos, on the bottom left section.

Comment: I understand that these elements or features are tied with the underlying logic of the plugin, but what I wanted to know, is if now the only thing to do is to reengineer the plug in, according to some considerations, in order to make it compliant with the LockerService standard?

Comment: The link of the second package, after editing it, according to Trevor's Suggestion: https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t0Y0000015iSo

Comment: @EndritSino I'm seeing the exact same behavior with and without LockerService enabled on your new package. Are you sure this is an issue with the 3rd party lib and not your component code? Maybe try getting an example online and verify full functionality with LockerService disabled, then activate it and see if there's any differences.

Comment: That's correct, but I simply followed your instructions.

Comment: That's fine. The comments are framed as though it's still a LockerService issue though and I want to make sure we make the distinction that after my recommended changes it is now an app level issue, not specific to Locker.

Comment: I understand, I will try to dig deeper on that. Anyway I am a bit confuesd because the code(the example as whole) is pretty straightforward, so the only thing that makes me wonder is if there might be a problem related with the lightgallery library that I am using(I mean the one that you suggested me).

Comment: When I tried I saw the counter number in the background change it was just mostly masked by the original number. Maybe that means there's a CSS issue. Try not including any unnecessary CSS.